# How to change data in row without refreshing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

Bootstrap vue table does not detect when there is a change. It shows when I refresh. How to change data in row without refreshing?  After I update the data, I want the data to be updated without making a get request again.

My Data:

```js
items = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Veli' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Berkay' },
  { id: 0, name: 'Mehmet' },
]
```

```html
<b-table
  :items="person"
  :fields="fields"        
/>

<template>
  <form
    v-for="(person, index) in persons" 
    @submit.prevent="submit"
  >
    <input v-model="person.name">
  </form>
</template>

<template>
  <div v-for="(person, index) in persons">
      <span :key="index">{{person.name}}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      persons: []
    }
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    this.$store.dispatch("loadPerson").then((response) => {
      Vue.set(this, "persons", response);
    })
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      axios.put('/person', this.person)
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think like this, we normally re-render the DOM with state. So changes in state cause the DOM to be updated.

If you don't have a lot of data, you can only update the changed data with the map method on the variable you hold your data, so I think the DOM will be updated as well.

However, if you receive a lot of data (eg thousands, millions), I think it would be better to send a GET request to the database again.

Because it would be unreasonable to use array methods on millions of data.